# Spyder - Invalid syntax pyflakes e - Only on Spyder

Tags: python, spyder

I am trying to replicate code from a youtube video tutorial, but I am getting the error "Invalid syntax pyflakes E", but I am not sure why...I am using Spyder IDE.

This is the tutorial link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bM50i7sKwwM&ab_channel=TechWithTim

```
import requests
import json

def login(mail, password):
    s = requests.Session()
    payload = {
        'email': mail,
        'password': password
        }
    res = s.post('http://api.giggl.app/v1/auth'), json=payload)
    s.headers.update({'authoirization': json.loads(res.content)['token']})
    print(res.content)
    return s

#user/pw
session = login('@gmail.com', 'q1231312123')
r = session.patch('https://api.giggl.app/v1/users/@me', json={'location': 'United States'})
print(r.content)
```

Comment: If look carefully you will see that the code highlighting is broken from some point on. There's your error, a missing `'`.

Comment: Ah..oops ty. I added that ' in front of the URL but I still have the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: @KlausD. The code highlighter itself doesn't seem to handle scrollable text very well.

Comment: You do, however, have a stray `)` following the URL in your call to `post`. Aside from that, there are no syntax errors in the code shown.